# Radial gradient background programmatically in UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, background, gradient, radial

I researched a lot but I cannot find a proper solutions. I want to add a radial background to a `UIViewController` which fits to a iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 screen (view See attached screenshot). The background should be done programmatically because i have several Scrollview with a height more than view.bounds.

Does anybody know a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow two different ways to achieve this.

The simple way. If you have an image (you posted a screenshot) wrap it into an `UIImageView`.
Once done you can add it as a subview of your controller's `view` sending it to back like the following.

```
UIImageView* radialImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radialBackground"]];
[radialImage setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
[[self view] addSubview:radialImage];   
[[self view] sendSubviewToBack:radialImage];
```

The not simple one. Create a custom `UIView` (named `RadialBackgroundView` for example) and override `drawRect:` method.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Take a look to CGContextDrawRadialGradient to draw radial gradient
}
```

You can use it like a simple image.

```
RadialBackgroundView* radialView = [[RadialBackgroundView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
[[self view] addSubview:radialView];    
[[self view] sendSubviewToBack:radialView];
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, i want to create a radial background like the attached image programmatically. i got massivly confused trying out CGContextDrawRadialGradient.